# Natural Transformation of Bifunctors

Tags: category-theory, functors, natural-transformations

I had a hard time proving the statement: "a transformation between two bifunctors is natural if and only if it is a natural transformation in each of it's arguments". This is Proposition no. 2, p. 38 of Saunders Mac Lane's textbook "Categories for the Working Mathematician".

Any hints?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Try making use of identity laws for the category, and composition laws for the functor.

Comment: Many thanks for the hint Dan. I will try.

Answer (score 2):

I assume by bifunctor you mean a functor $\mathcal A\times\mathcal B\to\mathcal C$.

**Hint:** If $f:A\to A'$ in $\mathcal A$ and $g:B\to B'$ in $\mathcal B$, then
$$(f,1_{B'})\circ(1_A,g)\ =\ (f,g)\ =\ (1_{A'},g)\circ(f,1_B)\,.$$

Comment: Hi. Yes, that is exactly what I meant by "bifunctor". Thank you for that hint. I will try.